# ¿Cómo puedo conseguir una ruta guardada desde SQL en byte y mostrar en DataGridView C#?

Tags: c#, gridview

¿Cómo puedo conseguir una ruta de un documento de **Word** guardado en mi base de datos **SQL** almacenado en formato **Bytes** para mostrarlo en mi `Datagridview` y pasar esa ruta a un cuadro de texto y luego abrir mi archivo.

Lo que quiero obtener es la ruta en la grilla para luego desde la grilla convertir ese arreglo de bytes en String para pasarlo hacia un `TextBox`, y desde ese `TextBox` tengo un Comando que me abrirá el archivo **Word/PDF** o cualquier otro tipo.

El problema es el siguiente, cuando quiero mostrar los datos en la grilla me da un error que me dice que no puedo mostrar ese formato y me sale una imagen de una X.

Comment: Vamos por partes, primero lo importante: visita estos enlaces http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask En segundo lugar, agrega el código que has realizado, también el error que te sale y cualquier otro detalle que sea de utilidad para que la familia de SOes puedan entender con mayor claridad la pregunta y por ende, ayudarte a solucionarla :D Lo que entiendo es que tienes el archivo de word en la base de datos y lo que quieres es obtener una ruta en una grilla para abrir el archivo, sin embargo no existe ruta ya que el archivo físico está en la BD

Comment: Exactamente ya esta guardo en la BD entonces como haría si quisiera volver ese archivo nuevamente a su ruta en la PC?

Comment: Al parecer `@Christopher R. Santos Cruz` levantó los documentos desde el sistema de archivos hacia la base de datos, y lo que está intentando es restaurarlos en la ruta de la que los obtuvo.

Answer (score 1):

Si desde a db puedes recuperar el byte array del archivo solo tendrias que usar

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\carpeta\archivo.docx", bytesFile):
```

para usar la clase File debes definir el using a System.IO

Ahora bien con esto tendras un archivo fisico con los bytes que recuperas de la db, pero no hay una ruta fisica antes, lo que debes mostrar en el grid es algun boton o icono que represente el documento en la db y al presionarlo ir con el Id de ese documento, recuperarlo, generar el archivo fisico y mostrarlo, embebido en el grid no muestras nada antes solo le dices que ay un documento pero lo recuperas cuando se presione la opcion.

Usas el Id de la tabla para identificar que documento se selecciono editar en el grid, usando el

```
SELECT campofile FROM Tabla WHERE Id=@id
```

recuperas el byte array del archivo

[[WinForms] Edición Empleados](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2011/02/winforms-edicion-empleados-grabar.html)

En la celda del grid puedes mostrar una imagen que tengas en la tabla,pero no archivos